# How to find $p(a \mid b \cap c)$ given $p(a \mid b)$ and $p(a \mid c)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> How to find $p(a \mid b \cap c)$ given $p(a \mid b)$ and $p(a \mid c)$?

Can this be done? I'm trying to write code for a simulation where an event a might be dependent two or more other known events.

For example, if $A$ happens .5 of the time when $B$ happens, and .8 of the time when C happens, what are the odds of $A$ if both $B$ and C already happened? Can I figure that out?

Comment: Use MathJax to type your question. You can find a tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

(Standard notation for probability theory tends to use uppercase letters for events so I will write A,B,C instead of a,b,c in this answer.)

It's going to depend on the specific events $A,B,C$ and how they depend on each other. Based on your comment on my deleted post it seems you know lots of conditional probabilities, such as $P(B|C)$ and $P(C|B)$, so maybe you are interested in an approach like this.

By the definition of conditional probability,
$$ P(A | B \cap C) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B \cap C)} .$$

You can calculate $P(B \cap C)$ from $P(B|C)$ and $P(C)$, for example:

$$ P(B \cap C) = P(B|C) P(C) .$$

You can calculate $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ also in lots of different ways. For example

$$ P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(C) P(A \cap B | C) .$$

Plugging these in gives
$$ P(A | B \cap C) = \frac{P(A \cap B | C)}{P(B|C)} .$$

Comment: Hmm, but I'm not sure I know P(A∩B|C). But I do know P(A|C),P(B|C), and P(A∩B). Do I just not have enough info?

Comment: My guess is that you don't have enough info with only those "single" conditional probabilities, yeah. The wikipedia articles on independence have various counterexamples that might be helpful in more rigorously asserting this claim.

Answer (score 0):

I obtain answer in some particular case, if it helps in someway.

Suppose $b,c$ are independent i.e.$P(bc)=P(b)P(c)$. Then
$$P(a|bc)=\frac{P(abc)}{P(ac)P(ab)}\cdot P(a|b)P(a|c)$$
Is "coefficient" $\frac{P(abc)}{P(ac)P(ab)}$ convenient?

In general case, when we know nothing more, then $P(a|bc)$ can be any:

1. if $a \subset bc \Rightarrow P(a|bc) =1$
2. if $a \cap bc=\emptyset \Rightarrow P(a|bc) =0$